# Batch extract from multiple .db files

Tags: sqlite, batch-file

I have many `.db` sqlite3 files. Files are in separated subfolders and most of them have same file name: `base.db`.
Every file contains a table '`main`' and I want to extract table from every .db file to separate csv file, so that every csv is extracted in the same subfolder next to .db file.

I tried with this script

```
cd C:\sqlite-tools-win32-x86
for /R %%G in (*.db) do sqlite3 -csv -header "%%G" "select * from main" > %%~nG.csv
```

The problem is, this script is reading `.db` files from subfolders, but extract csv's in root folder, and also overwrites previous csv file. 
I hope the explanation is clear. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are redirecting the output to `%%~nG`, which is the base name because of the `~n` modifier. To get also the full path to the parent directory use also [`~d` and `~p`](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html):

```cmd
cd /D "C:\sqlite-tools-win32-x86"
for /R %%G in (*.db) do (
    sqlite3 -csv -header "%%~G" "select * from main" > "%%~dpnG.csv"
)
```

I also replaced `cd` by [`cd /D`](https://ss64.com/nt/cd.html) in order to also change the drive just in case.